# I want to fill up a textbox and then click on submit button using python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, captcha

I want to fill up a textbox and then click on submit button using python. After clicking on the submit button, a opo up comes up with a captcha to be solved. I want to further read that captcha image to convert it into text and enter the security mechanism. Here is what I have already tried'

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('www.abc.com')
id_box = browser.find_element_by_id('EnterNo')
id_box.send_keys('1234567890')
```

Upto this point the code is working. But, I am not able to click on the submit button after this, i.e. the below code is not working

```
submit_button = browser.find_element_by_name('SubmitButton')
submit_button.click()
```

This throws the following error :

```
ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <input id="SubmitButton" name="SubmitButton" type="hidden"> could not be scrolled into view
```

Comment: @DebanjanB - This is not a duplicate. I want to fetch the captcha after clicking on the submit button and solve it. This is a totally different question. Why have you marked it duplicate??

Comment: Reopened the discussion !!!

Comment: Are you sure you are able to click on this element? `type='hidden'` doesn't have any rendering on the screen. Try sending ENTER to the `id_box` to trigger a submit. You can also call `id_box.submit()` which should also trigger a form submit.

Answer (score 2):

seems the button cannot be clicked due its out of view-side.
You need to scroll and then click.

Here is an example JS code for scroll to web element and click it.

```
element = driver.find_element_by_id("element id");
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true); arguments[0].click();", element);
```

**Update**

Actions can also do the job:

```
actions = ActionChains(driver)
element = driver.find_element_by_id("element id")
actions.move_to_element(element).click(element).perform()
```

Comment: Hi, I tried what you mentioned but I am getting the below error :
ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <input id="SubmitButton" name="SubmitButton" type="hidden"> could not be scrolled into view
The input type is hidden for this button. How can I click it then?

Comment: can you manually check if its clickable and what is the type of the button when you manually scroll to it.

Comment: It is a submit button and yes it is clickable. After clicking on it a captcha pops up in a new screen.

Comment: Here is the tag info :     
<input type="hidden"  id="SubmitButton" name="SubmitButton" value="Submit"/>

Comment: did your automation scroll to the element with JS executor from the example i provided ? p.s. i have update the answer with actions class move & click.

Comment: It threw WebDriverException: Message: TypeError: rect is undefined exception